# How to use R shiny to implement the concept of session / state / work flow

Tags: r, shiny

I’ve been trying to create a Shiny app, where the user first specifies a valid dataset, then they specify a valid model, and only then can they press a button to apply the model to the dataset.  The point is that what is presented to the user should depend on the state of things, e.g.  the ‘Apply Model to Data’ button doesn’t appear unless both the dataset and model are valid.

The question is how to should I code for the concept of a session (state changing in response to the user’s progress). I’ve been trying to do this using conditionalPanel() were I reuse state information I have determined. For instance I might calculate output$bValidData and output$bValidModel. I then try to use this state info in several places in ui.R, e.g. multiple places with conditionalPanel( condition =” output.bValidData == ‘TRUE’”, ….) 
However, it turns out an output.bValidData can only appear once in ui.R, otherwise the HTML generated is invalid. See

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/39

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/743

P.S. On the server my state info is being updated in a timely manner (I've checked) but the client isn't. I create my state info using reactives and ensure they are updated using outputOptions(), i.e.

```
output$bValidData <- reactive ({ … }); 

outputOptions(output, 'bValidData', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

My question then is – How should I implement state info? I don’t want to create a separate output.bValidData1, output.bValidData2, etc. for every place I use that state info.
I’m sure this has been addressed as it must be a common issue but I can’t find the any advice on it.

Comment: Could you please add some basic minimal example of what you already have? With that it will be easier that someone can just add the missing part.

Comment: I found a solution to this issue. That is to use the uiOutput() function (accompanied by renderUI() in server.R), in place of conditionalPanel(). A good intro to this is to be found [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html).